# How do I put C int's into an NSArray?

Tags: ios, objective-c, c, arrays, nsarray

When I make an NSArray with the normal `alloc` and `initWithObjects` with the object at index[0] is a string, everything works fine. However, if the first object is a `int` as such:

```
NSArray *anotherArrayObject = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:  5 , 6 , 3 , 1 ,@"3412817", nil];
```

I get an error ("Incompatible integer to pointer conversion sending 'int' to parameter of type 'id'") and a warning ("Implicit conversion of 'int' to 'id' is disallowed with ARC").

Any fixes for this?

Answer (score 2):

NSArray can only contain Objective-C objects (e.g. instances of `NSObject` and its subclasses*), not C primitive types like *int* (or *long*, *char **, etc). You will need to box or "containerize" your values.

For example:

`[ [ NSArray alloc ] initWithObjects:[ NSNumber numberWithInt:5 ], nil ] ;`

Or, same code using NSNumber literal expression:

`[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@5, nil]`

Comment: Or, for constant integers, simply `@5`.

Comment: Note that this is a NSNumber *literal*, and not "boxing syntax".

Comment: @Martin Why do you say it is a literal and not boxing, it is, there is no NSNumber literal. The syntax is literal but the result is boxing. One can not have this statement `NSNumber *i6 = @4;` outside a method, it is not a compile time literal in the same manner of `NSString` literals.

Comment: @Zaph: According to http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html, `@42` is called a "NSNumber literal", and `@( <expression> )` is called a "boxed expression".

Comment: So you are saying @3 is not boxed? Then what is it? Why can't is be used in the same way as @"string". For @"string" llvm creates an compile time  literal, for @3 a method must be called at run-time -- that boxes it.

Comment: @Zaph: I did not say that `@3` is not created at runtime, or that you can use it outside of a method or functions. I just stated how it is called in the Clang documentation. `@[..]` and `@{..}` also are created at runtime, but they are called "container literals" in the Clang documentation.

Answer (score 1):

`NSArray` can only contain objects so an `int` needs to be converted to a `NSNumber` to be contained in an `NSArray`.

updating the question statement:

```
NSArray *anotherArrayObject = @[ @5, @6, @3, @1, @"3412817" ];
```

Here are sone examples of converting an `int` to a `NSNumber` and putting it in an `NSArray`.

Using the `NSNumber` literal syntax:

```
NSArray *a = @[@5];
NSArray *b = @[@5, @6];
```

in place of the more verbose:

```
NSArray *a = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@5, nil];
```

If you have an `int` variable:

```
int i = 3;
NSArray *a = @[@(i)];
```

Inorder to recover the `int`:

```
int i = [a[0] intValue];
```